# How can I prevent auto initialization firebase on ios?

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working with firebase unity plugin on ios. I want to prevent firebase auto initialization and ask user for push notification permission later in the app. But firebase shows its annoying permission dialog on app startup.

- Plugin version 5.4.4;
- Xcode version 10.1;
- Test device iPad ios 12.1.4.

And YES I've read this
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client#prevent_auto_initialization and tried to implement many times. It doesn't work.
I've put this pair into my Info.plist:

```
<key>FirebaseMessagingAutoInitEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

Firebase just ignore this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault (as usual). Just forget to remove this code from my FCMHelper class.

```
public void OnDestroy()
    {
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived -= OnMessageReceived;
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived -= OnTokenReceived;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, any access to elements of сlass "Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging" causes the FCM to continue initializing with a request for access to push notifications.
When starting the application, you need to check whether the user agreed or not to access push notifications. If you haven’t given it yet (the request for access to push notifications has never been displayed), then you must prohibit any work with "Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging" until the moment you need it. Otherwise, you can safely start working with "Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging" at the time the application starts.